# Windows 10 laptop: is it possible to find when the laptop charger was plugged-in the last time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, charger

I have Windows 10 laptop. I cannot find the laptop charger. So, I am trying to recall when the laptop charger was plugged-in the last time. On Windows 10 is it possible to find when the laptop charger was plugged-in the last time? In other words: does Windows 10 track "charger plugged-in / out" events?

Comment: Press "win + r" then type "eventvwr" then press enter. If you are lucky you will find something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 does not track such events, so you need third-party software
for that.

You could for example use
[Power Event Provider](https://github.com/hirschmann/powereventprovider):

> Power Event Provider is a Windows service which posts power events such as power scheme changes, battery status changes, display state changes, etc. into the Windows event log. Besides for monitoring purposes, these events can also be used as triggers for the Windows task scheduler. This makes it possible to run any application or script when a power event occurs.

You can use it to configure the data you want, then use the Event Viewer
to find this data.

Answer (score 26):

Yes you can.

On a command prompt, type `powercfg /batteryreport`. Then open the resulting file `C:\Users\<username>\battery-report.html`. You will see a list of dates and times when the power state changed between Active/Battery and Active/AC (meaning using a charger).

Comment: This shows when the connected charger was used to provide charge, but not when the charger was connected, which I believe is what the OP is asking for. My laptop has been on a power supply since around 6pm last night, but the events shown are when the charging state moves between Active and Suspended. There have been 4 such events in the last 24 hours, but the charger hasn't been unplugged from the laptop.

Comment: @spikey_richie: The existence of substates of "plugged in" doesn't mean that "unplugged" can't be distinguished.  The answer doesn't say that "suspended" means charger disconnected, it says to look for "Active/Battery".

Comment: @spikey_richie Presumably if it's not plugged in *right now* (your glasses are on your forehead!) then the last time it was plugged in was right before the computer switched to battery mode.

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, the "charger is plugged in / out" (1) and the "charger is started / stopped providing the charge" (2) are two diff. events. The (2) depends on the (1). I am looking specifically for (1), however (2) may be useful too.

Comment: I've generated the report. In the "Usage history" there is "PERIOD" (1 week). Is there an (perhaps undocumented) option to show the _exact date and time_ rather than period?

Comment: @pmor it will give you exact times for the last three days by default, but you can extend that to 14 days by adding /duration 14

Comment: As others have mentioned, this command will show when the charger was plugged in (or not), but only if the laptop was active. Plugging the charger in/out while the laptop is suspended is not recorded.

Answer (score 2):

> does Windows 10 track "charger plugged-in / out" events?

No. Not natively on any any laptop I have seen. Battery health is often tracked but not charger connect / disconnect.

If you cannot find the charger, use the Manufacturer's specifications to find the manufacturer's specific chargers and see if a local computer shop can supply the proper part or a warranty approved part.